# Perl: Extracting multiple numbers from string

Tags: regex, perl

Could someone help me in correcting me for the following code. 
I want to extract the two numbers from a input string.

```
  input string [7:0] xxxx
```

I want '7' and '0' to be loaded into two variables (min and max). 
I am trying to achieve this by

```
my ($max, $min);
($max, $min) = $_ =~ /[(\d+):(\d+)]/;
print "min: $min max $max\n";
```

I am getting a result as

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at constraints.pl line 16, <PH> line 165.
min:  max: 1
```

regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[` and `]` are regex meta characters, so you have to escape them

```
($max, $min) = $_ =~ /\[(\d+):(\d+)\]/;
```

The brackets are used to denote a character class: `[ ... ]` which matches the characters inside it, e.g. `[abc]` matches `a`.

Comment: And additionally, you can combine lines 1 and 2, like this: `my ($max, $min) = $_ =~ /[(\d+):(\d+)]/;` I like to declare and assign in one step whenever that's possible.

Comment: @Andrejovich If you keep the backslashes, yes you can. Normally, I would say you would see the shortest form of them all: `my ($max, $min) = /\[(\d+):(\d+)\]/`, where the `$_ =~` part is implied. This often looks confusing to beginners.

Comment: d'oh, you're absolutely right. I should've copy/pasted *your* code, not the OP's.

Answer (score 0):

TLP is correct.
`[]` is meta character and any such character is required escaping like . `() [] *` etc to use it for literal match.
This would solve your problem.

```
($max, $min) = $_ =~ /\[(\d+):(\d+)\]/;
```

You may get warning if `$max` or `$min` or both would be blank i.e. `[ 7: ]` or `[ : ]` or `[ : 2]` or `[ ]` .